# How to integrate web components in Vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, spring, vaadin, boot

I was searching for a ready-to use web component for my Vaadin&Spring Boot application, and faced some questions.
As a person who does not into JS and frontend at all, i'm struggling in integration of those components. Currently I'm interested in this one: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/bluewatertrackspaper-countries/overview. I simply do not know what to do after adding a dependency via Maven. Could someone explain a way how to use those components similarly to default Vaadin components, using java classes?

Comment: Found this guide in Vaadin official documentation, still don't get it, but it can be useful for someone https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/web-components/integrating-a-web-component

Comment: Did you try their tutorials? Personally i found [this one](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tutorial/overview) quite helpful and easy to follow.

Comment: This is the latest docs for Vadin 23 https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/web-components

Comment: And there is this blog post too, note also the three training videos linked in the blog: https://vaadin.com/blog/creating-a-custom-component-with-lit

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the webcomponent you linked is built with polymer2. You can't use it in Vaadin 14+, except if you are running it in compatibility mode which I don't recommend.

It's easier to do it in Java with a Combobox.